# MongoDB : count documents for each year using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

i have this structure for my documents :

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("60ae47705c4eb3d38a25b8c6")
  number : 784
  date : 2019-06-18T21:59:39.000+00:00
  price : 5715
}
```

And i want to retrieve the sum of documents for each year like this :

```
{
  ...
  2019 : 28
  2020 : 35
  2021 : 15
}
```

It's the first time i use noSQL so i'm a bit lost.

I tried this :

```
Offre.aggregate([
    {"$facet" : {
            "2016" : [
                {"$match" : {"dateLivraison" : {"$gte" : new Date(2015,31,12), "$lt" : new Date(2017,1,1)}}},
                {"$count" : "2016"}
            ],
            "2017" : [
                {"$match" : {"dateLivraison" : {"$gte" : new Date(2016,31,12), "$lt" : new Date(2018,1,1)}}},
                {"$count" : "2017"}
            ],
            "2018" : [
                {"$match" : {"dateLivraison" : {"$gte" : new Date(2017,31,12), "$lt" : new Date(2019,1,1)}}},
                {"$count" : "2018"}
            ],
            "2019" : [
                {"$match" : {"dateLivraison" : {"$gte" : new Date(2018,31,12), "$lt" : new Date(2020,1,1)}}},
                {"$count" : "2019"}
            ],
            "2020" : [
                {"$match" : {"dateLivraison" : {"$gte" : new Date(2019,31,12), "$lt" : new Date(2021,1,1)}}},
                {"$count" : "2020"}
            ],
            "2021" : [
                {"$match" : {"dateLivraison" : {"$gte" : new Date(2020,31,12), "$lt" : new Date(2022,1,1)}}},
                {"$count" : "2021"}
            ],

        }},
    {"$project" : {
        "2016": {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$2016.2016",0]},
        "2017": {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$2017.2017",0]},
        "2018": {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$2018.2018",0]},
        "2019": {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$2019.2019",0]},
        "2020": {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$2020.2020",0]},
        "2021": {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$2021.2021",0]}
        }}
],   (error,data) =>{
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    }
})
```

but it gives me an empty result

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $group aggregation pipeline.

Mongoose:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-group

Mongo:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here : https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-use-mongoose-to-group-by-date-1210

So for my problem I used this :

```
Offre.aggregate( [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y", date: "$dateLivraison" } },
            total: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
],   (error,data) =>{
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    }
})
```